# Zooming out on pandas table in Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: macos, jupyter-notebook, export

I am attempting to take a screenshot of a correlation table made with pandas in Jupyter Notebooks but since it is very wide I must scroll to the right in order to view the whole table. On a mac it is not possible to scroll left or right while taking a screenshot so I am unable to capture the entire table. Is there anyway to get the entire table (doesn't have to be a screenshot an export of some type would work as well)?

Answer (score 0):

Is the table already shown in markdown? If not, you can try `df.to_html()`. From there, you can convert it to pdf, see (https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-pdf)

Otherwise you can plot the pandas table with matplotlib and remove the axis etc.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas.table.plotting import table 

ax = plt.subplot(111, frame_on=False) # no visible frame
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)  # hide the x axis
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)  # hide the y axis

table(ax, df)  # where df is your data frame

plt.savefig('table.png')
```